# OJS 3.1.1.4 Plugins Tab doesn’t load

Tags: php, fsockopen, ojs

I have the problem that I saw as OJS Admin I would not have the necessary rights to watch the plugins tab. The exact wording of the alert is "The current role does not have access to this operation."

otherwise no error message will appear in the JS Console.

[image]

It runs the version 3.1.1.4, which is instaliert over the git Repo.

If I look in the Error Log of Apache there are the following Errors:

```
PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/www/ojs/lib/pkp/classes/file/wrappers/HTTPFileWrapper.inc.php on line 77, referer: https://hard-times-magazine.org/index.php/Hardtimes/management/settings/website
PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/ojs/lib/pkp/classes/file/wrappers/HTTPFileWrapper.inc.php on line 77, referer: https://hard-times-magazine.org/index.php/Hardtimes/management/settings/website
PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://pkp.sfu.ca:443 (Unknown error) in /var/www/ojs/lib/pkp/classes/file/wrappers/HTTPFileWrapper.inc.php on line 77, referer: https://hard-times-magazine.org/index.php/Hardtimes/management/settings/website
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in /var/www/ojs/lib/pkp/classes/plugins/PluginGalleryDAO.inc.php on line 57, referer: https://hard-times-magazine.org/index.php/Hardtimes/management/settings/website
```

It runs the php version 7.2.10 on the machine.

The certificate is from Letsencrypt and is also registered in php.ini at openssl.cafile.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in OJS 3.1.1-4:

https://github.com/pkp/pkp-lib/issues/4024

...and is fixed in this commit, which will be included in the next release:

https://github.com/pkp/pkp-lib/commit/d27ef7d08c96ad3b60c77feba4f19688d00ac284

The stable branch for OJS 3.1.1 (ojs-stable-3_1_1) includes this, and is stable to run in production, if that's a good option for you.

Comment: I've already pulled branch ojs-stable-3_1_1 today and still have the bug.

Comment: I have now manually written the two plugin parts in the files and now everything works. The commit does not seem to be in ojs-stable-3_1_1 yet.